# How to display messages on pop without page reload?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to display the messages on my popup form without a page reload but when I hit the button it reloads the page and no message shows.

My Controller:

```
$current_password = $user->password;
if(md5($request_data['password']) == $current_password) {
    $user_id = $user->id;
    $obj_user = User::find($user_id);
    $obj_user->password = md5($request_data['new_password']);;
    $obj_user->save();
    return response()->json([
        'success_message' => 'password has been changed successfully',
    ], 422);
} else {
    return response()->json([
        'modal_message_danger' => 'wrong old password'
    ], 422);
}
```

My Ajax:

```
$('#password_change_form').submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var saveThis = this;
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/changepassword",
     data: $(saveThis).serialize(),
     success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
     }
   });
});
```

But it does nothing; Ajax is not working. I want to display the message.

[image: currently it's showing like this]

[image: this is my popup form where I want to display my message]

Comment: Please post your corresponding .blade.PHP file

Answer (score 0):

To get jquery object, I think you need to change

```
var saveThis = this;
```

to

```
var saveThis = $(this);
```

Comment: Hi i am having another problem

Comment: what is another problem?

Comment: i am having alert in my popup model but i want to show a message there success messages

Comment: i think nobody can solve your issue as far as you don't share blade files