# How to show flash message instead of alert box in popup from?

Tags: php, laravel, popup

My code displays an alert box in my popup form but I want to display the flash message in my popup form:

My Ajax:

```
$('#password_change_form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var saveThis = this;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/changepassword",
        data: $(saveThis).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            $('#password_change_form')[0].reset();
            alert(data);
        },
    });
}),
```

My Controller:

```
$current_password = $user->password;

if(md5($request_data['password']) == $current_password) {
    $user_id = $user->id;
    $obj_user = User::find($user_id);
    $obj_user->password = md5($request_data['new_password']);
    $obj_user->save();
    $success_output = '<div class="alert alert-success">Password changed</div>';
} else {
    $errors_output = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Wrong old password</div>';
    $error = array(
                'error'   =>  $errors_output
            );
    echo json_encode($error);
}

$success = array(
    'success'   =>  $success_output
);
echo json_encode($success);
```

Here I want to show the success message in my popup form:

```
<div class="modal fade common_modal" id="change_password" tabindex="-1"
    role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                    aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">Ã—</span>
                </button>

                <h3>ZmÄ›na hesla</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <form role="form" id="password_change_form"
                    class="common_form_style popup_form">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            <span id="form_output"></span>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password" style="width:100%">PÅ¯vodnÃ­ heslo </label>
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
                                <span toggle="#password-field" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="new_password" style="width:100%">NovÄ› heslo</label>
                                <input id="new_password" type="password" class="form-control" name="new_password">
                                <span toggle="#password-field" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>
                                <span class="help-block" style="color:#737373;font-size:14px;float:right;margin-right: 30px;font-weight: 100 !important;">MinimÃ¡lnÄ› 8 znakÅ¯, jedno velkÃ© a malÃ© pÃ­smeno a ÄÃ­slo</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="heslo znovu">PotvrzenÃ­ heslo</label>
                                <input id="password_confirmation" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation">
                                <span toggle="#password-field" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="submit-btn text-center">
                                <input type="submit"class="btn btn-default chci" value="UloÅ¾it" id="submit_form">
                            </div>

                            <div style="margin-top:10px;" id="success-messages"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12 pull-right"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

I Want to display a success message but currently there is alert in my popup form. The alert screen shot:

[image: alert box]

Comment: at first, you should fix js from this my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52673184/how-to-display-messages-on-pop-without-page-reload

Comment: okay i did it but same response alert on popup

Answer (score 0):

Please change to this js code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var saveThis = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./index.php",
            data: $(saveThis).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                // I don't know where you want to show messages.
                // In this case, outputting to id="form_output" element.
                $('#form_output').html(obj.success);
            }
        });
    });
});
```